# How to change the number of items displayed for different screen sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, cycle2

I'm trying to find a way to change the number of `carouselVisible` items for different screen sizes. I want in a screen resolution of 768px to show 3 items and when you scale down in 360 to have 1 item.

Is that possible?

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sb_satchitanand/r29A9/8/)

**jquery**

```
$('#carousel').cycle({
allowWrap: true,
carouselVisible: 5,
prev: '#prev',
next: '#next',
carouselFluid: true,
timeout: 0,
slides: 'article',
fx: 'carousel'
});

var slideshows1 = $('#carousel').on('cycle-next cycle-prev', function (e, opts) {
slideshows1.not(this).cycle('goto', opts.currSlide);
});
var slideshows2 = $('#carousel1').on('cycle-next cycle-prev', function (e, opts) {
slideshows2.not(this).cycle('goto', opts.currSlide);
});
$('#carousel article').click(function () {
var count = $("#carousel1 .readmore").length - 1;
var selectedIndex = $('#carousel').data('cycle.API').getSlideIndex(this);
var index = selectedIndex<count ? selectedIndex: (selectedIndex-count)%count;
slideshows1.cycle('goto', index);
slideshows2.cycle('goto', index);
});
```

**Html**

```
        <div class="service">
         <h1>Lead1</h1>
    </div>
</article>
<article>
    <div class="service">
         <h1>Lead2</h1>
    </div>
</article>
</div>
<div id="carousel1" data-allow-wrap="true" data-cycle-prev="#prev" data-cycle-next="#next" class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-timeout="0" data-cycle-manual-fx="scrollHorz" data-cycle-slides=".readmore">
<div class="readmore">
     <h2 class="lead">Lead</h2>

    <p>Testing some text right here</p> <a class="cta" href="#">Läs mer</a>

</div>
<div class="readmore">
     <h2 class="lead">Lead1</h2>

    <p>Testing some text right here</p> <a class="cta" href="#">Läs mer</a>

</div>
<div class="readmore">
     <h2 class="lead">Lead2</h2>

    <p>Testing some text right here</p> <a class="cta" href="#">Läs mer</a>

</div>
</div>
<div id="next">next</div>
<div id="prev">prev</div>
```

Comment: you can do that by writing different code for different window size :) `if ( $(window).width() > 739) {     
  //Add your javascript for large screens here
}
else {
  //Add your javascript for small screens here
}`

Comment: **Many Thanks, Can you show me a demo please**

Comment: kindly check http://jsfiddle.net/r29A9/16/

Comment: change the width as per need

Comment: check the following screenshot  when width>739(you give your own width) http://picpaste.com/screencapture-jsfiddle-net-r29A9-16-1458712714667-OBB3KIsf.png

when width < 739
http://picpaste.com/screencapture-jsfiddle-net-r29A9-16-1458712748839-erx40nY5.png

Comment: **Thank you @ RRR, this is what I was looking for... And it works**

Comment: ** HI @RRR, Can I change 5 different sizes, 768, 1000, 1400, 1600, etc. So it need just copy paste from the existing code ? Sorry for asking I am just beginner for jquery. :) **

Comment: Okay  I got it, Thanks  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends, if you need to adjust dynamically, when your user resizes a page, you would do something like this:

```
var properties = {
    allowWrap: true,
    carouselVisible: 5,
    prev: '#prev',
    next: '#next',
    carouselFluid: true,
    timeout: 0,
    slides: 'article',
    fx: 'carousel'
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    var height = $(window).height();
    var slideAmount;

    if (width >= 768) {
        slideAmount = 3;
    } else if (width <= 360) {
        slideAmount = 1;
    } else {
        slideAmount = 2;
    }

    if (properties.carouselVisible != slideAmount) {
        $('#carousel').cycle('reinit');
    }
});
```

If you only want to do it once, then, obviously, you would just get initial screen size:

```
var width = $(window).width();
var height = $(window).height();

// Instantiate your carousel with parameters based on screen size
```

Comment: Just store your carousel options in a separate object, then check for if (width <= 360) {properties.carouselVisible = 3; $('#carousel').cycle('reinit');}

Answer (score 0):

you can use easily swiperjs and you can set breakpoints. from example

```
    <Swiper
    slidesPerView={1}
    spaceBetween={10}
    pagination={{
      clickable: true
    }}
    breakpoints={{
      "640": {
        slidesPerView: 2,
        spaceBetween: 20
      },
      "768": {
        slidesPerView: 4,
        spaceBetween: 40
      },
      "1024": {
        slidesPerView: 5,
        spaceBetween: 50
      }
    }}
    className="mySwiper"
  >
    <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>Slide 5</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>Slide 6</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>Slide 7</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>Slide 8</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>Slide 9</SwiperSlide>
  </Swiper>
```